# How do I adjust the my GLSL code to add additional light sources?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, light

In the code below I am trying to implement a fragment shader program for Phong:

```
// Inputs from application.
// Generally, "in" like the position and normal vectors for things that change frequently,
// and "uniform" for things that change less often (think scene versus vertices).  

in vec3 position_cam, normal_cam;
uniform mat4 view_mat;

// This light setup would usually be passed in from the application.

vec3 light_position_world  = vec3 (10.0, 25.0, 10.0);
vec3 Ls = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // neutral, full specular color of light
vec3 Ld = vec3 (0.8, 0.8, 0.8);    // neutral, lessened diffuse light color of light
vec3 La = vec3 (0.12, 0.12, 0.12); // ambient color of light - just a bit more than dk gray    bg

// Surface reflectance properties for Phong model below.

vec3 Ks = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // fully reflect specular light
vec3 Kd = vec3 (0.32, 0.18, 0.5);  // purple diffuse surface reflectance
vec3 Ka = vec3 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);    // fully reflect ambient light

float specular_exponent = 400.0;   // specular 'power' -- controls "roll-off"

// Shader programs can also designate outputs.
out vec4 fragment_color;           // color of surface to draw in this case

void main () 
{

    fragment_color = vec4 (Kd, 1.0);

}
```

I have two questions:

1. How do I add 2 additional directional light sources to my code? Do I simply add more vec3 Ld variables to my light setup or is there something else I must do?
2. How do I set the Phong exponent high enough to produce sharp and bright highlights?

Comment: In glsl you can use arrays and loops. Store the data in a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object).

Comment: But how does that help me? Im not sure I follow. If I'm adding more light sources, don't I simply need to add more light variables like light_position_world?

Comment: Yes, but use an array of structures. A ssbo makes it easier to update the variables

Comment: Can you give an example of how that would be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In glsl you can use arrays and structures. Define an array of light sources. See [Array constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Array_constructors) and [Struct constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Struct_constructors):

```c
const int no_of_lights = 2;

struct TLightSource
{
   vec3 lightPos;
   vec3 Ls; 
   vec3 Ld;
   vec3 La;
   float shininess;
};

TLightSource lightSources[no_of_lights] = TLightSource[no_of_lights](
    TLightSource(vec3(10.0, 25.0, 10.0), vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8), vec3(0.12, 0.12, 0.12), 10.0),
    TLightSource(vec3(-10.0, 25.0, 10.0), vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.8, 0.0, 0.0), vec3(0.12, 0.0, 0.0), 10.0)
);
```

User a for loop to iterate through the light sources and sum up the light color for ambient, diffuse and specular light (e.g [Phong reflection model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model)):

```c
void main()
{
    vec3 normalInterp;
    vec3 vertPos;

    vec3 normal = normalize(normalInterp);
    
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    for (int i=0; i < no_of_lights; i++)
    {
        color += Ka * lightSources[i].La;

        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightSources[i].lightPos - vertPos);
        float lambertian = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0); 
        color += lambertian * lightSources[i].Ld;

        if (lambertian > 0.0) 
        {   
            vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vertPos);
            vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
            float RdotV = max(dot(reflectDir, viewDir), 0.0); 
            float specular = pow(RdotV, lightSources[i].shininess/4.0);
            color += specular * lightSources[i].Ls;
        }
    }

    frag_color = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```